# Added new field in checkout, but how to save it in address book?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have added a custom field in checkout using this [plugin](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-field-in-checkout.html), but what if I’d like to add that field permanently, also to the customer’s address, so that it can be edited in My Account->Address Book?

After adding

```
<div class="field">
                    <label for="billing:ssn" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('SSN') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="custom[ssn]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getQuote()->getSsn()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('SSN') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" id="billing:ssn" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

to `template\customer\address\edit.phtml` the page stops loading after

```
value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getQuote()->getSsn()) ?>"
```

(my new field and fields that were meant to be below are not displayed)

When I change value to normal text it loads without problems (but the value written in my new field won't save, obviously), so it appears loading problem is caused by this particular code which doesn’t seem to work with Adress Book – how can I fix it?

**EDIT:**
I can see in database that the plugin saves values correctly in tables `sales_quote_custom` and `sales_order_custom`, so I have no idea why it can't read them in Address Book.

Comment: have you try this...$this->getAddress()->getSsn();

Comment: I tried, it gives no errors, but it won't save the entered value either...

Comment: if you want to save Extra field in the address book then you have to use other extension because this extension is saving the value at the time of Checkout.

Comment: First try setting some static value i.e. `$this->getAddress()->setSsn('SomeValue)` and then retrieve it like `$this->getAddress()->getSsn()`. If it works you can save that value as a customer attribute just like other attributes are saved in Magento.